# Property of Prime Counting Function

Tags: prime-numbers

For $ n $ be a positive integer and $ f(n) = \dfrac{\pi^2(n)}{n} $, where $ \pi(x) $ is the number of the prime numbers less than $x$ . 
Then find the value of $\displaystyle S = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(2k)\right).$

By the computation, it seems to be $ S=1 $. But I cannot prove this.

Comment: I had an important mistake. Sorry.

Comment: Due to [PNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} f(2k)\right)=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\pi^2(2k)}{2k}\right)\approx \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2k}{\left(\ln(2k)\right)^2}\right)$$